# How to develop and add individual pages which will together form a PDF document using go-wkhtmltopdf in Go?

Tags: html, go, templates, wkhtmltopdf

I'm creating a report generator using Go as server side language. There will be defined header(containing logo image) and footer and dynamic table content which will be populated. There will be 20 rows table on each page including the header and footer. How to generate each page so that the pages don't get mixed i.e header of next page starts on previous page itself.

Currently I'm using go-wkhtmltopdf to convert HTML to Go. But than the header of next page starts on previous page, so the page orientation is disturbed as the table is broken in between pages. I want to have each new page starting with header.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS property [page-break-before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-before) to control the page break. And remove the header/footer from the content and provide them to `go-wkhtmltopdf` directly. See the demo below:

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
    "strings"

    wkhtml "github.com/SebastiaanKlippert/go-wkhtmltopdf"
)

var html = `
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .page {
        page-break-before: always;
        font-size: 20pt;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page">Hello</div>
    <div class="page">World</div>
  </body>
</html>
`

func main() {
    pdfg, err := wkhtml.NewPDFGenerator()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    page := wkhtml.NewPageReader(strings.NewReader(html))

    // The header/footer are provided standalone.
    page.HeaderCenter.Set("[page]")
    page.HeaderLine.Set(true)

    page.FooterHTML.Set("footer.html")

    // the following parameters are passed to footer.html in the query.
    page.Replace.Set("hello", "world")
    page.Replace.Set("my_id", "123457789")

    pdfg.AddPage(page)
    pdfg.MarginTop.Set(10)
    pdfg.MarginBottom.Set(10)

    err = pdfg.Create()

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = os.WriteFile("temp.pdf", pdfg.Bytes(), 0o644)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

And here is the **footer.html** file:

```golang
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function subst() {
        var vars = {};
        var query_strings_from_url = document.location.search
          .substring(1)
          .split('&');
        for (var query_string in query_strings_from_url) {
          if (query_strings_from_url.hasOwnProperty(query_string)) {
            var temp_var = query_strings_from_url[query_string].split('=', 2);
            vars[temp_var[0]] = decodeURI(temp_var[1]);
          }
        }
        var css_selector_classes = [
          // these values are provided by wkhtmltopdf.
          'page',
          'frompage',
          'topage',
          'webpage',
          'section',
          'subsection',
          'date',
          'isodate',
          'time',
          'title',
          'doctitle',
          'sitepage',
          'sitepages',

          // these values are provided by the "replace" option.
          'hello',
          'my_id',
        ];
        for (var css_class in css_selector_classes) {
          if (css_selector_classes.hasOwnProperty(css_class)) {
            var element = document.getElementsByClassName(
              css_selector_classes[css_class]
            );
            for (var j = 0; j < element.length; ++j) {
              element[j].textContent = vars[css_selector_classes[css_class]];
            }
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="border: 0; margin: 0" onload="subst()">
    <table style="border-top: 1px solid black; width: 100%">
      <tr>
        <td class="section"></td>
        <td class="hello"></td>
        <td class="my_id"></td>
        <td style="text-align: right">
          Page <span class="page"></span> of <span class="topage"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a work around, I have set A4 page height, and similar sections heights(like header, body, footer). This worked for me.

```css
<style>
    .top-logo {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 15mm;
        margin-right: 15mm;
        width:90%;
    }
    img {
        height: 15mm;
        width: 30mm;
    }
    .content {
      margin-left: 5mm;
      margin-right: 0mm;
      text-align: left;
      height: 325mm;
    }
    .report-table {
      width: 100%;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    .report-table td {
      border: none;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    .report-table tr:first-child {
      border-top: 1px solid black;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
    .general-details {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: 2.5mm;
      width: 125mm;
      text-align: left;
    }
    .additional-details {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 125mm;
      margin-right: 5mm;
      text-align: left;
    }
    .wordbreak {
      word-break: break-all;
      white-space: pre-line;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    .details-container {
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .bold-text {
      font-weight: bold;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    .foot {
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    html{
        height:297mm;
        width:255mm;
    }
  </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Publisher Report</title>
</head>

<body>

  {{range .Pages}}
  <div style="height: 380mm;display: block;">
      <div class="top-logo">
        <img src="https://www.computerhope.com/cdn/media/logo-200-gray.png" alt="Logo 1" style="float :left">
        <img src="https://www.computerhope.com/cdn/media/logo-200-gray.png" alt="Logo 2" style="float: right;">
      </div>
      <div class="content">
            <h2 style="text-align:center;">PROOF OF PERFORMANCE REPORT </h2>

            <div class="details-container">
                <div class="general-details" >
                    <table style="table-layout: fixed;">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="bold-text">Network Name:</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="bold-text">Total Players:</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td class="bold-text">Total Duration:</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td class="bold-text">Total Impression:</td>
                      </tr>
                        
                    </table>
                </div>
            
                <div  class="additional-details">
                    <table style="table-layout: fixed;">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="bold-text">Generated On: </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="bold-text">Date Range:</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="bold-text">Type:</td>
                    </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="bold-text">Media Items: </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <table class="report-table" style="table-layout: fixed;">
                <colgroup>
                  <col style="width: 44%;">
                  <col style="width: 34%">
                  <col style="width: 11%">
                  <col style="width: 11%;">
                </colgroup>
                <tr style="padding: 3%;">
                  <th style="padding-top: 1%;padding-bottom: 1%;">AdName</th>
                  <th style="padding-top: 1%;padding-bottom: 1%;">AdGroupName</th>
                  <th style="padding-top: 1%;padding-bottom: 1%;">Impression</th>
                  <th style="padding-top: 1%;padding-bottom: 1%;">Duration</th>
              </tr>
                    {{range .Rows}}
                    <tr>
                        <td class="wordbreak">{{.AdName}}</td>
                        <td class="wordbreak">{{.AdGroupName}}</td>
                        <td class="wordbreak">{{.Impression}}</td>
                        <td class="wordbreak">{{.Duration}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {{end}}
                    <br>
                    
            </table>
      </div>     
            <div class="foot">
                <h2>{{.Current_page_no}} of {{.Total_no_of_pages}}</h2>
            </div>
      
  </div>
  
  {{end}}

</body>
</html>
```